# fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found for Flutter 2.2.3

Tags: flutter, ios-simulator

Ever since I have upgraded to Flutter 2.2.3, I have been coming across this issue

**fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
#import "Flutter/Flutter.h"**

for the two plugins

1. Shared Preferences
2. URLLauncher

The post-install of my pod file is

```
post_install do |installer|
installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
target.build_configurations.each do |config|
config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.0'
end
end
end
```

However, when I change it to

```
post_install do |installer|
installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
end
end
```

It gives the following error

**The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.5.99.**

flutter doctor -v output

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on macOS 11.5 20G71 darwin-x64, locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 2.2.3 at /Users/ritikadesai/flutter
    • Framework revision f4abaa0735 (3 weeks ago), 2021-07-01 12:46:11 -0700
    • Engine revision 241c87ad80
    • Dart version 2.13.4

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/ritikadesai/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6916264)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.5.1, Build version 12E507
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6916264)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.58.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.24.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • iPhone 12 Pro (mobile) • 2173457A-60B4-46EB-9EB0-B1AC72A84782 • ios            •
      com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-5 (simulator)
    • Chrome (web)           • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 91.0.4472.114

• No issues found!
```

I have tried everything including deleting the Podfile, Podfile.lock, Pods folder, upgrading flutter, changing channels from Stable to Master to Beta, creating a new project and copying the iOS folder

Nothing is working and I've been stuck on this for days now.

Any help is appreciated

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot of solutions, but only one worked for me.

1. `rm -rf ios`
2. `flutter create .`
3. `flutter pub get`

I would lost app icon on iOS and some other things, but if you use git, could restore files you need easily.